# Application of Weierstrass M- Test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Suppose that the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}n|b_n|$ converges. Show that the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}b_n \sin{nx}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, and that it can be integrated and differentiated term by term.

So I have to use the Weierstrass M-test. Put $M_n=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|b_n \sin{nx}|=|b_n|$. Now we want to show that $\sum_{1}^{\infty}M_n =\sum_{1}^{\infty}|b_n|$converges then $\sum_{1}^{\infty}b_n \sin{nx}$ converges uniformly.

Do I need to bound $\sum_{1}^{\infty}M_n$ by $\sum_{1}^{\infty}n|b_n|$? I understand the that it can be integrated and differentiated term by term if $\sum_{1}^{\infty}b_n \sin{nx}$ converges uniformly  on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Weierstrass M-Test is just another way of saying the Absolute Convergence Test, except it applies to complex sequences. Im really not sure what the difference is, and if there isnt a practical one then it seems rather trivial to solve.

Comment: I understand that but how do i show that the series converges uniformly @CogitoErgoCogitoSum

Comment: Isn't this a comparison of $b_n \leq nb_n$?

Comment: $b_n \sin(nx) \le b_n \le |b_n| \le n |b_n|$

Comment: Got it @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The series $\sum b_n\sin nx$ converges uniformly by Weierstrass M-test; here it is enough to estimate $|b_n\sin nx|\leqslant |b_n|$ and use that 
$$
\sum |b_n|\leqslant \sum n|b_n|<\infty . 
$$
A similar argument holds for the differentiated series $\sum nb_n\cos nx$ and the integrated one. Note that termwise differentiation and integration is automatic for power series but not for general series.